# How do I use multiple h:messages or p:messages on one page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces **p:messages** but I think this question applies equally to **h:messages**

I have a composite component to handle login/logout at the top of every page.  (It is in the Facelets template.)   To handle login errors, it has a **p:messages** component in it.

In the content area, I typically have a form that also has a **p:messages** in it.  However if the form processing ever produces a message, I end up getting a message rendered from the login component as well as the place where I intended.

This is hardly a fatal problem, but I would like to clean this up.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primefaces `p:messages` has an attribute `redisplay`. Set

```
redisplay="false"
```

to instruct the message tag to only display messages that are not yet displayed on the page.

Comment: Well dang how did I miss that.  Thanks for the tip.