# How to have more than one <h:message> on a xhtml page, showing different content

Tags: java, ajax, validation, jsf, message

How can I have more than one `<h:message>` tag showing different content in a page?

I'm validating an `inputtext`, like this:

```
Title: <h:inputText id="input"
            value="#{insertDocController.docController.documentBean.title}"
            required="true" requiredMessage="Required!">
            <f:ajax  execute="@this" render="message" event="blur" />
            </h:inputText>         
            <h:message for="input" id="message" style="color:red" />
```

This page is intended to submit some information about documents. After I submit each document, I'd like to show a confirmation message, the code for the submit button is this:

```
 <h:commandButton id="submit" value="insert" action="#{insertDocController.submit}" />
             <h:messages id="submitMessage" />
```

And the `submitMessage` is generated on the `submit()` method:

```
public void submit() throws IOException {   
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
        String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
        byte[] bytes = uploadedFile.getBytes();

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("submitMessage", 
            new FacesMessage(String.format("File '%s' type '%s' successfully " +
                    "submitted!", fileName, contentType)));

        this.docController.submit();
}
```

When I test it, leaving the `inputtext` empty and clicking the `submit button`, the page displays one red message next to the `inputtext` for title and a black one next to the submit button, but both showing the same content: "Required!"

On this link:[How do I use multiple h:messages or p:messages on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861342/how-do-i-use-multiple-hmessages-or-pmessages-on-one-page) they talk about a similar problem, but with `<p:message>` from primefaces. They say the solution is to set the property `redisplay` from `<p:message>` to true. `<h:message>` doesn't have this property. Is there any property to `<h:message>` similar from the redisplay from `<p:message>` ?

What's the solution for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `globalOnly="true"` into `h:messages`

```
<h:messages id="submitMessage" globalOnly="true" />
```

and when you create the submit message set the clientId to null

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
        new FacesMessage(String.format("File '%s' type '%s' successfully " +
                "submitted!", fileName, contentType)));
```

Comment: thank you for the answer... I tested it, but now it only shows the validation message for the required inputtext, it doesn't show the confirmation message, after I click the submit button..

Comment: I found that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861342/how-do-i-use-multiple-hmessages-or-pmessages-on-one-page that talks about the same problem but with <p:message>. They talk about using a property called redisplay from <p:message> , but <h:message> doesn't have it. Is there any similar property for <h:message>

Comment: Okay let me get it straight, you should fill the inputText, submit then you would have the successful message. If your inputText is empty that means you have a validationError, and the lifecycle won't proceed to call your submit method. it's the expected bihavour @Luciane

Comment: In fact, I've edited my post now, because I forgot to write that the event for the inputtext required message is blur. If I don't fill that inputtext, click on it and then out, the message shows, normally. But the other message should show after I click the submit button, it's a confirmation and it's not showing.When I only had the submit message it was working, it stopped working properly after I added the required message for the inputtext.

Comment: You might need a better understanding of the JSF lifecycle.
If any of your components in the page fails the validation phase (which is your required field, fails the validation when it's empty) , your SUBMIT method won't be call, hence your message won't be added on the context. @Luciane

Comment: YES! You are right after the change you suggested it's working properly, because, if I fill the inputtext and click submit, the submitting message appear. I don't know how I didn't see it. Thank you so much!